# Vector Iterators Incompatible (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, queue, graph-algorithm

I was trying to implement some Graph Algorithms so continuing by testing I received an error in GNU C++ compiler (Segmentation Fault). In Visual Studio I saw the cause is "vector iterators incompatible". But how this happens? The error is thrown in shortestPathBFS function in the line "getName()" when I try to access a field of visitor object. Visitor is an element of Vertice* queue, so it must not depend on queue iterator in my opinion. If you can explain me why, I will be appreciated.

```
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//#define traverse(container,iterator) \
//for(typeof(container.begin()) iterator = container.begin(); iterator != container.end(); iterator++)

class Edge;
class Vertice
{
private:
    string name;
    vector<Edge*> incidences;
    bool visited;
public:
    Vertice() {name = "NULL"; visited = false;}
    Vertice(string name) {this->name = name; visited = false;}
    void setName(string name) {this->name = name;}
    string getName() {return name;}
    bool isVisited() {return visited;}
    void setVisited() {visited = true;}
    void setUnvisited() {visited = false;}
    void connectTo(Vertice*);
    void connectTo(Vertice*,int);
    void printNeighbors();
    vector<Vertice*> getNeighbors();
};

class Edge
{
private:
    int cost;
    Vertice *start,*end;
public:
    friend class Vertice;
    Edge() {cost = 0;}
    Edge(Vertice * start, Vertice * end) {this->start = start; this->end = end;} 
    Edge(Vertice * start, Vertice * end, int cost)
    {this->start = start; this->end = end; this->cost = cost;}
    Vertice* getEnd() {return end;}
    Vertice* getStart() {return start;}
};

void Vertice::connectTo(Vertice * w)
{
    incidences.push_back(new Edge(this,w));
}

void Vertice::connectTo(Vertice* w,int cost)
{
    incidences.push_back(new Edge(this,w,cost));
}

vector<Vertice*> Vertice::getNeighbors()
{
    vector<Vertice*> temp;
    for(vector<Edge*>::iterator it = incidences.begin(); it != incidences.end(); it++)
    {
        temp.push_back((*it)->getEnd());
    }
    return temp;
}

void Vertice::printNeighbors()
{
    for (vector<Edge*>::iterator i=incidences.begin(); i!= incidences.end(); i++)
    {
        cout<<(*i)->start->getName()<<"--"<<(*i)->cost<<"--"<<(*i)->end->getName()<<endl;
    }
}

class Graph
{
public:
    // using set for non-comparable elements are not good
    // but this is for exercising
    set<Vertice *> vertices;
public:
    void initGraph()
    {
        Vertice *v;
        v = new Vertice("IST");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("ANK");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("IZM");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("BER");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("TOR");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("BEJ");vertices.insert(v);
        v = new Vertice("PER");vertices.insert(v);

        (*findByName("IST"))->connectTo(*findByName("ANK"),10);
        (*findByName("IST"))->connectTo(*findByName("IZM"),5);
        (*findByName("IST"))->connectTo(*findByName("BER"),61);

        (*findByName("IZM"))->connectTo(*findByName("ANK"),3);
        (*findByName("IZM"))->connectTo(*findByName("TOR"),98);
        (*findByName("IZM"))->connectTo(*findByName("BER"),70);

        (*findByName("BER"))->connectTo(*findByName("ANK"),59);
        (*findByName("BER"))->connectTo(*findByName("TOR"),91);

        (*findByName("ANK"))->connectTo(*findByName("PER"),77);
        (*findByName("ANK"))->connectTo(*findByName("BEJ"),151);

        (*findByName("BEJ"))->connectTo(*findByName("TOR"),48);
        (*findByName("TOR"))->connectTo(*findByName("ANK"),100);
        (*findByName("PER"))->connectTo(*findByName("BEJ"),162);
        (*findByName("TOR"))->connectTo(*findByName("PER"),190);
        (*findByName("BEJ"))->connectTo(*findByName("PER"),163);
    }

    set<Vertice*>::iterator findByName(string name)
    {
        for(set<Vertice*>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++)
        {
            if ((*it)->getName() == name)
            {
                return it;
            }
        }
        return vertices.end();
    }

    int shortestPathBFS(Vertice * start, Vertice * finish)
    {
        queue<Vertice *> q;
        q.push(start);

        Vertice *visitor;
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            visitor = q.front();q.pop(); 
            visitor->setVisited();
            cout<<"BFS : "<<visitor->getName()<<endl;
            if (visitor->getName() == finish->getName())
            {
                break;
            }
            for(vector<Vertice*>::iterator it = (visitor->getNeighbors()).begin(); it != (visitor->getNeighbors()).end(); it++ )
            {
                if (!(*it)->isVisited())
                {
                    q.push((*it));
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void printAll()
    {
        for(set<Vertice*>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++)
        {
            (*it)->printNeighbors();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Graph g;
    g.initGraph();
    g.printAll();
    g.shortestPathBFS(*(g.findByName("IST")),*(g.findByName("PER")));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this line in `Graph::shortestPathBFS`:

```
for(vector<Vertice*>::iterator it = (visitor->getNeighbors()).begin(); it != (visitor->getNeighbors()).end(); it++ )
```

The problem is that you cannot compare iterators from two different containers (even if the containers are the same type), but `visitor->getNeighbors()` returns a new object each time it is invoked. Consequently, `it` is initialized from one object then compared to an iterator from a different object.

Rewrite the loop as:

```
vector<Vertice*> neighbors = visitor->getNeighbors();
for(vector<Vertice*>::iterator it = neighbors.begin(); it != neighbors.end(); ++it)
{
    if (!(*it)->isVisited())
    {
        q.push((*it));
    }
}
```